# Adding all Binary Rasters in a Directory Using Raster Calculator in a Standalone Python Script

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, raster-calculator

I have a directory with binary raster files (1 band only) which I need to add in a standalone python script. The problem is the rasters have different number of rows and columns and different resolution (reading them in as numpy arrays and adding them does not work). When I use the raster calculator, it manages to do what I want, but now I need to use it outside QGIS and do it automatically for all rasters in the folder. How can I add all my rasters in my directory inputFolder and create one output raster? I have the following code so far:

```
inputFolder = "/home/usr/Desktop/"

def findRasters(path, filter):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, filter):
        for file in fnmatch.filter(files, filter):
            yield os.path.join(root, file)

entries = []

for l in findRasters(inputFolder, '*.tif'):
    fileInfo = QFileInfo(l)
    baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
    rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(l,baseName)
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer) 
    layer = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
    layer.ref = l.name() + '@1'
    layer.raster = l 
    layer.bandNumber = 1
    entries.append(layer) 

expression = '(' + entries[1].ref + ' + ' + entries[0].ref + ')'
calc = QgsRasterCalculator(expression,'/home/usr/Desktop/final.tif',
                           'GTiff',
                           layers[0].extent(),
                           layers[0].width(),
                           layers[0].height(),
                           entries)

calc.processCalculation()
```

I am not sure how I should formulate my `expression` such that it takes into account all rasters in the folder

Comment: Without an idea of the raster commands you use, we can do nothing.

Comment: I added the commands I want to use for the Raster Calculator, however no output raster is created

Comment: you want to merge all the raster files or apply the same processing to all the rasters ?

Comment: I want to add all rasters together and save that as a new raster

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see more code's been added since my previous answer :)

Ran this from the python console, you may need other imports if calling outside of QGIS.

Made a few small changes, namely

- Added imports
- need to set the QgsRasterCalculatorEntry.raster to rlayer (a QgsLayer instance), not the name of the layer
- Added a list, `layers`, which gets filled with the layers in the loop
- Added a one liner to create the complete sum expression.
- Adds the result layer

This runs to completion. I'm afraid I don't have many good data sets to test this on. But it seems to work. As with your code it will use the extent and resolution of the first layer.

```
import os
import fnmatch
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry

inputFolder = "/path/to/rasters"
outputfilename = '/tmp/final.tif'

def findRasters(path, filter):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, filter):
        for file in fnmatch.filter(files, filter):
            yield os.path.join(root, file)

entries = []
layers = []

for l in findRasters(inputFolder, '*.tif'):
    print l
    fileInfo = QFileInfo(l)
    baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
    rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(l,baseName)
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer) 
    layer = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
    layer.ref = rlayer.name() + '@1'
    layer.raster = rlayer
    layers.append(rlayer)
    layer.bandNumber = 1
    print layer
    entries.append(layer) 

reflist = " + ".join([ent.ref for ent in entries]) 
expression = '(' +  reflist + ')'
print expression

calc = QgsRasterCalculator(expression,outputfilename,
                           'GTiff',
                           layers[0].extent(),
                           layers[0].width(),
                           layers[0].height(),
                           entries)

calc.processCalculation()
print "Finished!"

fileInfo = QFileInfo(outputfilename)
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(outputfilename, baseName)
if not rlayer.isValid():
    print "Layer failed to load!"
else:
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! The above solution works in a standalone script with the addition of a few more imports. The most important thing that I changed in order to make the reflist definition work is to convert the QString to a python string: reflist = " + ".join([str(ent.ref) for ent in entries])

Answer (score 2):

You could use existing gdal tools.

there are two gdal command line utilities which you could call from your script using `os.system` or `subprocess.call`

[gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) - use this to create **copies** of each raster, scaled to the same size (use the `-ts` option to set resolution in pixels, or `-tr` in map units)

[gdal_calc](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html) - this allows you to do the summation on the standardised rasters. If you have no more than 26 rasters you can do this in one call, otherwise you need to do this in a loop (add raster1+raster2, then add raster3, then add raster4 etc)

Comment: Yes but the question is about a Python solution and not command lines, even if gdal_calc is a Python file

Comment: @gene, gdal commands maybe called via subprocess python module.

Comment: The problem is I need to replicate the exact results created via the raster calculator...I need to create a raster which is the sum of all rasters, extract the zeros from it and polygonize it. If I start scaling all rasters, I am afraid when I obtain the final raster and polygonize it, I might get different polygons